# How to retrieve console output when I run a command write of pyvisa on an instrument (serial connection)?

Tags: python, serial-communication, pyvisa

I'm trying to send a write command to an instrument using serial communication through PyVisa. After sending the command, the instrument runs an internal file and returns a log to the instrument's linux terminal. I would like to return the execution log of this file to the machine's terminal.

With SSH communication, I can return it through the code below (using stdout.readlines()):

```
def create_connection_ssh(self):
        self.ssh_amp = paramiko.SSHClient()
        self.ssh_amp.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        self.ssh_amp.connect(self.ip_amp, username=self.username_amp, password=self.password_amp)

def amplifier_clock_set(self):
        stdin, stdout, stderr = self.ssh_amp.exec_command('../../opt/scripts/config/amplifier_clock_set.sh')

        day = datetime.today().strftime('%d')
        month = datetime.today().strftime('%m')
        year = datetime.today().strftime('%Y')
        hour = datetime.today().strftime('%H')
        minute = datetime.today().strftime('%M')
        weekday = datetime.today().strftime('%a')
        montname = datetime.today().strftime('%b')
        
        stdin.write(f'{day}\n')
        stdin.write(f'{month}\n')
        stdin.write(f'{year}\n')
        stdin.write(f'{hour}\n')
        stdin.write(f'{minute}\n')

        result = ' '.join(stdout.readlines())
        error = ' '.join(stderr.readlines())
        print('Output: '+result+error)
```

And the code used for serial communication below: (The problem is here)

```
def create_connection_serial(self):

        RscManager = visa.ResourceManager()
        try:
            self.amplifier = RscManager.open_resource(self.amplifier_serial)
            self.amplifier.baud_rate = 115200
            self.amplifier.write_termination = '\n'
            self.amplifier.read_termination = '\n'
            time.sleep(0.5)

def amplifier_clock_set(self):
        self.amplifier.write('./amplifier_clock_set.sh')

        day = datetime.today().strftime('%d')
        month = datetime.today().strftime('%m')
        year = datetime.today().strftime('%Y')
        hour = datetime.today().strftime('%H')
        minute = datetime.today().strftime('%M')

        self.amplifier.write(f'{day}')
        self.amplifier.write(f'{month}')
        self.amplifier.write(f'{year}')
        self.amplifier.write(f'{hour}')
        self.amplifier.write(f'{minute}')

        print(self.amplifier.read()) #In this part, I need a command or a way to return the console output that is in the terminal of the instrument that ran the file.
```

Comment: What have you tried that isn't working? You may want to review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the question. Maybe now it's a little clearer. The SSH code part works correctly. However, the serial communication code did not work. The 'self.amplifier.read()' line returns an undesirable integer. Does PyVisa have any functionality that returns console output?

Comment: A serial data connection does not have a "console", unless it is happening inside a terminal. With the serial connection, you just send and receive data. If you are certain that the instrument is sending data but your code is not receiving it, then I would check the all the data transfer settings, like termination characters, baud rate, and encoding. For example, if you see integers but you expect ascii characters, maybe you need to decode the integers.

Comment: You haven't said anything about the instrument (e.g. make, model, etc) you're using. Could it be that the instrument has a completely different interface for serial comms? It could be that through serial comms, the instrument expects a set of commands (SCPI is a common for many instruments).